# exlude or not Gemfile and Gemfile.lock from _config.yml

Tags: jekyll

I am a beginner in jekyll.

Shall I exclude Gemfile and Gemfile.lock from _config.yml ? thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: You mean using to add them to the `exclude` key or anything else?

Comment: Hello Marcanuy, thank you for your answer. like the following : <br>exclude:
   - Gemfile
   - Gemfile.lock
#   - node_modules
#   - vendor/bundle/
#   - vendor/cache/
#   - vendor/gems/
#   - vendor/ruby/
   - Inger-Analytics-feb0aa8b73d1.json
   - .gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should exclude them, you don't want to have them in your final website, you just need them when Jekyll generates the site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marcanuy